# How to return a multiple value related into one specific key value in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I created the account and project schema. The project schema have `projectCreatorId` that is also same value of  my `_id` of a account. The result that I want is if the app fetch all the project in the list I want also to get the information related to the `projectCreatorId` that can be found in `accountModel`.

```
projectController.js
export const getProjectList = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    projectModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'accountModel',
            localField: 'projectCreatorId',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'output',
          },
        },
      ])
      .then((result) => console.log(result));
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ msg: error.message });
  }
};
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    _id: 6124f5d1b77aab39fc8db7ba,
    lastOpened: { date: 2021-08-24T13:36:17.364Z },
    projectCreatorId: 612630b5caec270758fcbc22,
    projectName: 'Project One',
    projectNotes: '',
    startDate: 2021-08-24T13:31:20.050Z,
    endDate: 2021-08-31T13:31:20.000Z,
    whoCanEdit: 'Admin',
    viewType: 'List',
    lastUpdate: 2021-08-24T13:36:17.364Z,
    createdAt: 2021-08-24T13:36:17.364Z,
    __v: 0,
    output: []
  },
  {
    _id: 6124f71db77aab39fc8db7c5,
    lastOpened: { date: 2021-08-24T13:41:49.957Z },
    projectCreatorId: 610fa182093746447c9c399f,
    projectName: 'Project Two',
    projectNotes: '',
    startDate: 2021-08-24T13:41:36.304Z,
    endDate: 2021-08-30T13:41:36.000Z,
    whoCanEdit: 'Everyone',
    viewType: 'List',
    lastUpdate: 2021-08-24T13:41:49.957Z,
    createdAt: 2021-08-24T13:41:49.957Z,
    __v: 0,
    output: []
  },
  {
    _id: 61252481b77aab39fc8db81c,
    lastOpened: { date: 2021-08-24T16:55:29.378Z },
    projectCreatorId: 610fa182093746447c9c399f,
    projectName: 'Project Three',
    projectNotes: '',
    startDate: 2021-08-24T16:55:13.490Z,
    endDate: 2021-08-31T16:55:13.000Z,
    whoCanEdit: 'Everyone',
    viewType: 'List',
    lastUpdate: 2021-08-24T16:55:29.378Z,
    createdAt: 2021-08-24T16:55:29.378Z,
    __v: 0,
    output: []
  }
]
```

AccountModel
[image]

projectModel
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) into an aggregation stage like this:

- `$lookup` to merge result comparing `_id` and `projectCreatorId`. It creates an array called `result`
- Then get the first position of the result array.
- And use `$project` to output only values you want.

```
db.account.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "project",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "projectCreatorId",
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "result": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$result",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id":0,
      "name": 1,
      "projectName": "$result.projectName",
      "projectCreatorId": "$result.projectCreatorId"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oaajsmoj2j3)

Comment: Sir @JF question this approach can only return Then get the first position of the result array? What if I got multiple projects related to one user? Tried to modify the example given to me but like what you said it only return one value.

Comment: According to your desired output I'm assuming you only have one match between IDs, otherwise the result is an array with all posible values: [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7HBzQ0gGYFm)